# Twitter does not want to log me in

Tags: c#, twitter

Can you guys help me login into the Twitter (http://twitter.com) with a webrequest?

I have done everything I could think of,

Here is my code (I have replaced my actual username and password for Twitter with USERNAME and PASSWORD):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
        string url = "https://twitter.com";
        var Webget = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = Webget.Load(url);
        CookieContainer temp = new CookieContainer();

        var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='authenticity_token']")
             .Attributes["value"].Value;

        Console.WriteLine(value);
        HttpWebRequest req =(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://twitter.com/sessions");
        req.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "session%5Busername_or_email%5D=USERNAME&session%5Bpassword%5D=PASSWORD&remember_me=1&return_to_ssl=false&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=" + value.Trim();
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
         req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Referer = "https://twitter.com/sessions";
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36";
    req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: is an exception thrown? do you get an error message? if so, what does it say?

Comment: @user1666620 it's not an exception it's show me "failed" message

Answer (score 2):

Instead of scraping web pages directly, you should rather use the Twitter API. There are some [.NET libraries available](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#dotnet).